# Purpose of base case in binary search tree deletion

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I am taking a course on algorithms and data structures in Python 3 and my instructor recently introduced us to the binary search tree. However, I am having trouble understanding the deletion algorithm. Below is the implementation we were taught, however when I initially wrote my own rendition, I did not include a "base case" and it still worked:

```
def remove(self, data):
    if self.root:
        self.root = self.remove_node(data, self.root)

def remove_node(self, data, node):
     if node is None:
        return node
    if data < node.data:
        node.leftChild = self.remove_node(data, node.leftChild)
    elif data > node.data:
        node.rightChild = self.remove_node(data, node.rightChild)
    else:
        if not node.rightChild and not node.leftChild:
            print('removing leaf node')
            del node
            return None
        if not node.leftChild:
            print('removing node with single right child')
            tempNode = node.rightChild
            del node
            return tempNode
        elif not node.rightChild:
            print('removing node with single left child')
            tempNode = node.leftChild
            del node
            return tempNode
        print('removing node with two children')
        tempNode = self.get_predecessor(node.leftChild)
        node.data = tempNode.data
        node.leftChild = self.remove_node(tempNode.data, node.leftChild)
    return node
```

Now, all of this makes sense to me except the statement below:

```
if node is None:
    return node
```

When we previously learned about base cases, we were taught that they were essentially the exit points for our algorithms. However, I do not understand how this is the case in the given code. For one, I do not see how a node could ever be empty and even if it was, why would we return an empty node? As far as I can see, this check serves no purpose in the overall recursion because we do not seem to "recur towards it" as we would in any other recursive function. I would greatly appreciate an explanation!

Comment: First, `del node` doesn't actually have any role in deleting the node. Second, why do you think you don't have a base case?

Comment: Sorry if I was misunderstood. I understand that my function has a base case, however, I do not understand the purpose of the base case in the context of the actual deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base case(s), in general, serve one or more purposes, these include;

1. preventing the function from recursing infinitely
2. preventing the function from throwing errors on corner cases
3. compute/return a value/result to callers higher up in the recursion tree

With tree deletion, the first point isn't really a concern (because the recursion tree will only have a finite number of nodes - same as the tree you recurse over). You will be concerned with points 2 and 3 here.

In your function, you *do* have a base case - in fact, you have two (thanks to @user2357112) -

1. The value-not-found portion, specified by

   ```
   if node is None:
       return node
   ```

   and,
2. The value-found portion, specified by your code inside the `else` statement, which performs the actual deletion.

To keep the behaviour consistent with the recursive cases, the value-not-found base case returns `None`. As you see, the first base case is consistent performs the second function of a generic base case outlined above, while the second base case performs the third.

Comment: That's not the base case, or at least not the whole base case. Most of the stuff after the `else` is also base case. `if node is None` is the value-not-found portion of the base case, while the `else` is the value-found portion.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks a bunch, edited the post into shape.

Comment: Your answer makes sense to me. However, is the first portion of the base case even necessary in this instance? Whenever the function is called recursively by callers higher up, it seems as though a node or branch is always returned and is thus propagated up the recursion tree. Thus what would be an example of a corner case that this "value-not-found portion" checks against?

Comment: @Markoe7: Deleting a value that isn't actually in the tree.

Comment: If this is the case, wouldn't it make sense to check whether the inputted data exists in the tree much earlier rather than letting it recur to the point in the tree where it would lie if it existed before triggering this part of the base case?

Comment: @Markoe7: Before that point, you don't know whether the value is even in there.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for all the help. Based on this logic, am I right in thinking that the code shown [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-2-delete/) is labeled incorrectly in the sense that the statements labeled as the _base case_ are actually only part of the whole, with the rest being the `else` statements with their returns?

Comment: @Markoe7 based on our discussion, it should be clear that that code isnsloppily labelled :)

Comment: Just making sure :) Thanks for all the help.

Comment: is sloppily*, sorry for the typo, was on a handheld device.

Comment: Again just to clarify, this code would be functionally identical if `return node` was replaced with `return None` correct? I have noticed that most implementations of BST deletion seem to favor the first approach. Is there some syntactical standard that says the first should be used rather than the second (which in my opinion makes the statement's purpose much more obvious)?

Comment: @Markoe7 functionally the same. It is a matter of taste really. I would imagine the second is more explicit but in this context they're both equally obvious.